# How is currentColor useful where color is inferred?

Tags: html, css

Spec:

> The value of the ‘color’ property. The used value of the `currentColor` keyword is the computed value of the ‘color’ property. If the `currentColor` keyword is set on the ‘color’ property itself, it is treated as ‘color: inherit’.
>
> [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor)

MDN:

> The currentcolor keyword represents the value of an element's color property. This lets you use the color value on properties that do not receive it by default.
>
> If currentcolor is used as the value of the color property, it instead takes its value from the inherited value of the color property.
>
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

However, if we look at the example given by MDN:

```html
<div style="color:blue; border: 1px dashed currentcolor;">
  The color of this text is blue.
  <div style="background:currentcolor; height:9px;"></div>
  This block is surrounded by a blue border.
</div>
```

And then modify it slightly to replace properties that require an explicit color with ones that don't, and to remove the use of of `currentColor`:

```html
<div style="color:blue; border: 1px dashed;">
  The shadow of this text is blue (without color being specified).
  <div style="box-shadow: 0 0 10px; height:9px;"></div>
  This block is surrounded by a blue border (without color being specified).
</div>
```

We see that color defaults to the inferred value where none is specified. Is there any practical benefit to using `currentColor` in these cases, or is this just a matter of poor examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to this is to be found in the specs from [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor).

> 4.4. ‘currentColor’ color keyword
>   CSS1 and CSS2 defined the initial value of the ‘border-color’ property to be the value of the ‘color’ property but did not define a corresponding keyword. This omission was recognized by SVG, and thus SVG 1.0 introduced the ‘currentColor’ value for the ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stop-color’, ‘flood-color’, and ‘lighting-color’ properties. CSS3 extends the color value to include the ‘currentColor’ keyword to allow its use with all properties that accept a  value. This simplifies the definition of those properties in CSS3.
>
> **currentColor**
>
> *The value of the ‘color’ property. The used value of the ‘currentColor’ keyword is the computed value of the ‘color’ property. If the ‘currentColor’ keyword is set on the ‘color’ property itself, it is treated as ‘color: inherit’.*

CSS 1 and 2 didn't have any keyword for this, but used the color value as their initial value if none were set. CSS3 has a value for this called `currentColor` however legacy behavior is to fall back on the color property.

*So the use in this case is to give more clarity to where the used color originates from.*

Comment: Fair enough, but if we're already using shorthand properties, clarity apparently isn't a primary concern.